# Kinect recognises too many swipe right gestures even if I sit still

Tags: c#, kinect, swipe, gestures

This is from my main window:

```
foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
{
    if (joint.TrackingState != JointTrackingState.Tracked)
        continue;

    if ((joint.JointType == JointType.HandRight) || (joint.JointType == JointType.HandLeft))
    {
        swipeGestureRecognizer.Add(joint.Position, kinectSensor, joint.JointType);
    }            
}
```

And my gestures are written like this:

```
// Swipe to right
if (ScanPositions((p1, p2) => Math.Abs(p2.Y - p1.Y) < SwipeMaximalHeight, // Height
            (p1, p2) => p2.X - p1.X > -0.05f, // Progression to right
            (p1, p2) => Math.Abs(p2.X - p1.X) > SwipeMinimalLength, // Length
            SwipeMininalDuration, SwipeMaximalDuration)) // Duration
{
    if (jointul == JointType.HandLeft)
    {
        SetClothByGesture(1, 0);
        RaiseGestureDetected("SwipeToRight");
    }
    return;
}

// Swipe to left
if (ScanPositions((p1, p2) => Math.Abs(p2.Y - p1.Y) < SwipeMaximalHeight,  // Height
            (p1, p2) => p2.X - p1.X < 0.05f, // Progression to right
            (p1, p2) => Math.Abs(p2.X - p1.X) > SwipeMinimalLength, // Length
            SwipeMininalDuration, SwipeMaximalDuration))// Duration
{
    if (jointul == JointType.HandRight)
    {
        SetClothByGesture(-1, 0);
        RaiseGestureDetected("SwipeToLeft");
    }
    return;
}
```

My logic is that if you swipe with your right hand to left then it would do something, if you swipe with your left hand to right it will do something else. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you only think you are sitting still but in reality you have a nervous tick and keep twitching. :)

Comment: Try increasing your movement threshold; Maybe 0.05 is too small?

Comment: it was 0.01 before and it worked. if I only use my right hand, it works, but if i try both hands then it starts to be buggy and unresponsive, and starts recognizing to many swipes right

Comment: Where is the history of the swipe stored?  What is the code that decides if you've hit `SwipeMininalDuration` or exceeded `SwipeMaximalDuration`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the code, instead of swipes, if the right or left hand is further than the head with 0.45f, then it does the command.